# Sum of different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods, sum

Can anyone help me to figure out how to get the sum from 2 different lengths of array. I am trying for to long but couldn't figure it out. I know that I need to have another loop. Here is my food until now

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.*;
public class Question1d{
public static void main (String [] args){
    double[] b = add(); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b)); 
}

public static double[] add(){
    double[] v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4};
    double[] w = {5, 4, 3, 3, 1};
    int a = v.length;
    int b = w.length;
    int capacity = Math.max(a,b);
    double[] s = new double[capacity];
    if (a==b){
        for (int i = 0; i<capacity; i++){
            s[i] = v[i] + w[i];
        }
    }

    return s;
} 
}
```

Or maybe there is another way. Thnx

eddit:
The method should return a new array of double formed by adding the corresponding elements of the input arrays. If one array is longer the sum should get elements of that array and the other array to be considerate as it has 0 values.

Comment: pls edit your question and write what you are expecting in resultant array for these two input arrays?

Comment: Also, you never talk about it being necessary that the arrays be of the same length.

Comment: You wrote, "sum from 2 different lengths of array".  What does that mean?  The code that you wrote (s[i] = v[i] + w[i];) doesn't make any sense unless the arrays are the same length.  What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I think he wants to sum the same indexes in each array, storing that value in a third array whose length is = the the largest array's length. I also think he's assuming IndexOutOfBounds = 0.

Comment: This code that i have done can calculate only if they are the same i am asking you to update for different lengths. I know that it is said a==b. And i know that i do not need that because after i will need 2 more if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
public static double[] add(){
    double[] v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4};
    double[] w = {5, 4, 3, 3, 1};
    int a = v.length;
    int b = w.length;
    int capacity = Math.max(a,b);
    double[] s = new double[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i<capacity; i++){
        s[i] = (i >= v.length ? 0 : v[i]) +  (i >= w.length ? 0 : w[i]);
    }


    return s;
}
```

Comment: i edited your answer removing the a==b statment to allow this case, great answer!

Comment: Thanks, that was a bad omission on my part :P

Comment: I changed (a != b), but I am having an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: check that the line reads s[i] = (i >= v.length ? 0 : v[i]) +  (i >= w.length ? 0 : w[i]);
 and not s[i] = (i >= v.length ? 0 : v[i]) +  (i >= w.length ? 0 : v[i]);

Comment: yes yes i have done that but i was trying also before with two food lopes but i was getting this error i think the array it is not updating the size somehow. Sorry for bothering

Comment: @Mark W can you please just tell me what dose this statement do (i >= v.length ? 0 : v[i]). Is it asking if i is smaller than v.length attach zero to i ?

Comment: @IlirV.Gruda sorry, I was away. Its a shorthand if like statement. It can be read as: if I >= v.length { return 0; } else { return v[I]; }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count sum of two arrays, just count sum of the first, then count sum of the second and finally sum of these two numbers.

```
    int sum1 = 0;
    for (int i : v)
        sum1 += i;

    int sum2 = 0:
    for (int i : w)
        sum2 += i;

    int result = sum1 + sum2;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need the sum of those two arrays to be shown in another array.